# How to append the object into existing json array of objects

Tags: javascript, json

I am having json object like below which will be dynamic,

```
let data_existing= [
       {
          "client":[
             {
                "name":"aaaa",
                "filter":{
                   "name":"123456"
                }
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "server":[
             {
                "name":"qqqqq",
                "filter":{
                   "name":"984567"
                }
             }
          ]
       },
               ]
```

From the inputs i will get an object like below,

```
let data_new =  {
      "client":[
         {
            "name":"bbbbb",
            "filter":{
               "name":"456789"
            }
         }
      ]
    }
```

I need to append this object into the existing "client" json object. Expected output will be like,

```
[
   {
      "client":[
         {
            "name":"aaaa",
            "filter":{
               "name":"123456"
            }
         },
         {
            "name":"bbbb",
            "filter":{
               "name":"456789"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "server":[
         {
            "name":"qqqqq",
            "filter":{
               "name":"984567"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

And, if the "data_new" is not exists in the main objects, it should as new objects like below, for example,

```
 let data_new =  {
          "server2":[
             {
                "name":"kkkkk",
                "filter":{
                   "name":"111111"
                }
             }
          ]
        }

output will be like,
[
   {
      "client":[
         {
            "name":"aaaa",
            "filter":{
               "name":"123456"
            }
         },
      ]
   },
   {
      "server":[
         {
            "name":"qqqqq",
            "filter":{
               "name":"984567"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
{
      "server2":[
         {
            "name":"kkkkk",
            "filter":{
               "name":"11111"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I tried the below method, but it is not working as expected. Some help would be appreciated.

Tried like below and not worked as expected,

```
function addData(oldData, newData) {
  let [key, value] = Object.entries(newData)[0]
  return oldData.reduce((op, inp) => {
    if (inp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    console.log("111");
      op[key] = inp[key].concat(newData[key]);
    } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(inp));
      op = Object.assign(op, inp);
    }
    return op
  }, {})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function seems to work when the `key` already belongs to `data_existing` (e.g.: "client").

But you have to handle the second use-case: when the `key` was not found in the objects of `data_existing` (e.g.: "server2").
This shall be performed after the `reduce` loop, adding the new item to `data_existing` if the key was not found.

Here is an example of how you could achieve that:

```js
function addData(inputData, inputItem) {
  const [newKey, newValue] = Object.entries(inputItem)[0];

  let wasFound = false; // true iif the key was found in list
  const res = inputData.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
    const [key, value] = Object.entries(item)[0];
    const keyMatch = key === newKey;
    if (keyMatch) {
      wasFound = true;
    }
    // concatenate the lists in case of key matching
    const newItem = { [key]: keyMatch ? [...value, ...newValue] : value };
    return [...accumulator, newItem];
  }, []);

  if (!wasFound) {
    res.push(inputItem); // if key was not found, add item to the list
  }
  return res;
}
```

Hope it helps.